# Count number of PDF files in Directory and output to .csv

Tags: powershell

I am trying to report on the number of pdf files in a directory. The below code works fine, however i have added Export-Csv into it, and the output does not work. The file is created, but the count is wrong. I get "#TYPE System.Int32" in cell 1A of the output file instead of the file count.... not sure why.

```
(get-ChildItem C:\Test\* -Filter *.pdf -Recurse).Count | Export-Csv C:\TEMP\Test.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export-CSV works better when you have an object or hashtable with properties and values. All you have is a number in this case and it has no idea what the column heading should be. If all you want is a number in a file, try this:

```
(get-ChildItem C:\Test\* -Filter *.pdf -Recurse).Count | Set-Content C:\TEMP\Test.csv
```

But if you really want a csv file or an example for other projects, try this:

```
$HashTable = @{NumberOfPDFFiles = ((get-ChildItem C:\Test\* -Filter *.pdf -Recurse).Count)}
$HashTable | Export-csv C:\TEMP\Test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Or something like this to stick with the one line idea

```
(get-ChildItem C:\Test\* -Filter *.pdf -Recurse).Count | 
    Select-Object @{n='PdfCount';e={$_}} | 
    Export-CSV C:\TEMP\Test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2):

To compliment kevmar's answer since it does address the issue but doesn't explain why.

From [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx)

> By default, the first line of the CSV file contains "#TYPE " followed
>   by the fully-qualified name of the type of the object.

That is why your first line is: `#TYPE System.Int32` and why `-NoTypeInformation` removes it. If all you are doing is outputting a count then `Set-Content` makes more sense.

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea why and it was kind of puzzling to me too.